# Loop over three level array

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

[image]Hello I have an array with three levels. The third level consist of an array with each one containing up to an array of 3 objects. Inside each object is its own data. I'm looking to loop over each array that contains the objects and collect the count of the status string. It will either be "Passed", "Failed". The data is dynamic and passed through to the UI using an API route with node.js using JSON.stringify. I have access to the entire array using,

```
 $.getJSON("/automation/api/pos_reports")
.then(addData)

  function addData(data) {
  var postotal = (data.posreports.length)
  $('#posTotal').append(postotal);

  let posreports = data.posreports;
  console.log(posreports)
```

I was advised using Ramda.js would be the easiest to use. Any assistance is appreciated. Open to using native JS, jQuery or a library like Ramda.js. Thanks.

Example array:

```
let data = [
    [
        [    
            {result: "Passed"},
            {result: "Failed"},
            {}
        ],
        [
            {result: "Passed"},
            {result: "Passed"},
            {result: "Failed"}
        ],
        [
            {result: "Passed"},
            {result: "Passed"},
            {result: "Failed"}
        ],
        [
            {result: "Passed"},
            {result: "Passed"},
            {result: "Failed"}
        ],
        [
            {result: "Failed"},
            {},
            {}
        ]
    ]
]
```

Comment: What do you mean by "collect the count of the status string"?

Comment: What are expected results?

Comment: I want to go through each result and get the total number of passes and the total number of failed to display on the UI.

Comment: @Mark White check.my answer. Does exactly that

Comment: Thanks @vicbyte I updated the post with an image of the data im working with, maybe you can assist? As you can see each results array can have up to 3 objects. Each object contains a 'result' for passed and failed. Wanting to get the total count, save to a variable so I can append to where I need it on the UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple loop is enough to achieve what you want, and doesn't use any extra resources. :)

@Edit: The example array you provided is in fact different from your actual data. In the example you have a 3-dimensional array, where in your data you have an array of objects that have an array of objects inside them. :) Thats why the code needed to be sligtly altered.

```js
    let data = [
      {"results": 
        [    
          {result: "Passed"},
          {result: "Failed"},
          {}
        ]
      },
      {"results": 
        [    
          {result: "Passed"},
          {result: "Failed"},
          {result: "Passed"},
        ]
      },
      {"results": 
        [    
          {result: "Passed"},
          {result: "Failed"},
          {}
        ]
      },
      {"results": 
        [    
          {result: "Passed"},
          {result: "Failed"},
          {}
        ]
      },
    ];

    let count = {"Passed": 0, "Failed": 0};

    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
      if (!data[i].results) continue;
      for (let j = 0; j < data[i].results.length; j++){
        let el = data[i].results[j].result;
        if (el) count[el]++;
      }
    }

    console.log(count);
```

Comment: Thank you for your response I really appreciate it, all of these do return a count but I think only your code and the one above return the total count for Passed and Failed instead of the total count in each object.

I do see that when going through the code and console.logging it does get down to the array of results but the pass and fail are returning 0.

Comment: Running the code for my data set returns 0, but it works fine for the data set I sent as an example. I attached an image of the data im working with, maybe will be more clear?

Comment: @MarkWhite Edited my code with explaination why it was working on the example dataset, but not on your actual dataset. :)

Comment: Awesome that did the trick. So now I have an object with two key: value pairs? Is there a way to separate them? I tried using split but I think that only works on arrays? I'd like to assign them to variables.

Comment: Yes. Thats an object with two properities (key/value pairs). Simplest way to assign an object property to variable: `let passed = count.Passed`

Comment: Sorry I should of known that.....lol you just make it so easy. Thanks again my friend I really appreciate your response and helping me out!

Comment: Thought you would be happy to know because of your help I was able to loop through another data array and return the result like a champ lol thanks!!!!

Comment: @MarkWhite no problem, everyone was a beginner at one point and glad you are able to use the solution to solve another problem. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use map to return an array of objects, with pass and fails. Make use of arrays map method :D

```js
let data = [
[
  [
    {result: "Passed"},
    {result: "Failed"},
    {}
  ],
  [
     {result: "Passed"},
    {result: "Passed"},
    {result: "Failed"}
  ],
  [
     {result: "Passed"},
    {result: "Passed"},
    {result: "Failed"}
  ],
   [
     {result: "Passed"},
    {result: "Passed"},
    {result: "Failed"}
  ],
   [
     {result: "Failed"},
    {},
    {}
  ]
 ]
]

function CountPassFail(arr)
{
  let hash = {'Passed': 0, 'Failed':0}
  arr.forEach(val => {
    if(!val.result) return;
    let res = val.result;
    hash[res] += 1;
  })
  return hash
}

console.log(data[0].map(cell => CountPassFail(cell)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, you can use reduce instead of map, if you want to consolidate into one hash

```js
let data = [
[
  [
    {result: "Passed"},
    {result: "Failed"},
    {}
  ],
  [
     {result: "Passed"},
    {result: "Passed"},
    {result: "Failed"}
  ],
  [
     {result: "Passed"},
    {result: "Passed"},
    {result: "Failed"}
  ],
   [
     {result: "Passed"},
    {result: "Passed"},
    {result: "Failed"}
  ],
   [
     {result: "Failed"},
    {},
    {}
  ]
 ]
]

function CountPassFail(arr)
{
  let hash = {'Passed': 0, 'Failed':0}
  arr.forEach(val => {
    if(!val.result) return;
    let res = val.result;

    hash[res] += 1;
  })
  return hash
}

let count = data[0].reduce((hash,cell) => {
  cellHash = CountPassFail(cell);
  hash.Passed += cellHash.Passed;
  hash.Failed += cellHash.Failed;
  
  return hash;
  }, {Passed: 0, Failed : 0});
  
  console.log(count);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try and flatten the array and reduce to one result:

```js
const data = [
  [
    [
      { result: "Passed" },
      { result: "Failed" },
      {}
    ],
    [
      { result: "Passed" },
      { result: "Passed" },
      { result: "Failed" }
    ],
    [
      { result: "Passed" },
      { result: "Passed" },
      { result: "Failed" }
    ],
    [
      { result: "Passed" },
      { result: "Passed" },
      { result: "Failed" }
    ],
    [
      { result: "Failed" },
      {},
      {}
    ]
  ]
];

const flatten = array =>
  array.reduce(
    (result,item)=>
      Array.isArray(item)
        ? result.concat(flatten(item))
        : result.concat(item),
    []
  )
;

console.log(
  flatten(data)
  .reduce(
    (result,item)=>{
      if(item.result==="Passed"){
        result.passed++;
      }
      if(item.result==="Failed"){
        result.failed++;
      }
      return result;
    },
    {passed:0,failed:0}
  )
);
```

If you want a different format of the totals then maybe this is what you had in mind:

```js
const data = [
  [
    [
      { result: "Passed" },
      { result: "Failed" },
      {}
    ],
    [
      { result: "Passed" },
      { result: "Passed" },
      { result: "Failed" }
    ],
    [
      { result: "Passed" },
      { result: "Passed" },
      { result: "Failed" }
    ],
    [
      { result: "Passed" },
      { result: "Passed" },
      { result: "Failed" }
    ],
    [
      { result: "Failed" },
      {},
      {}
    ]
  ]
];

const flatten = array =>
  array.reduce(
    (result,item)=>result.concat(item),
    []
  )
;

console.log(
  flatten(data)
  .reduce(
    (result,item)=>
      result.concat(
        item.reduce(
          (result,item)=>{
            if(item.result==="Passed"){
              result.passed++;
            }
            if(item.result==="Failed"){
              result.failed++;
            }
            return result;
          },
          {passed:0,failed:0}
        )
      ),
      []
  )
);
```